# Splash screen plugin not working when using file transfer plugin

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to display splash screen until my initial loading is done, but it is not working the splash comes and goes immediately

My code:

```
  <name>BlankCordovaApp3</name>
  <description>A blank project</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>`enter code here`
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" version="0.4.6" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.3" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

PS: to my surprise it is working fine if i remove the file-transfer plugin that is below code works as expected:

```
  <name>BlankCordovaApp3</name>
  <description>A blank project</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">Apache Cordova Team </author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.0" />
  <preference name="windows-phone-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <vs:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" version="0.3.3" />
  <vs:platformSpecificValues />
</widget>
```

Comment: file-transfer also has dependency on file plugin. Did you installed them both?

Comment: Yes, both of them are installed.